# MSAccess - Run Query that executes subquery/make-table

Tags: mysql, database, ms-access

**OBJECTIVE**

Create a report that fetches data from multiple tables (i.e Inventory, Item Detail, Purchase Orders).

*NOTE: **Inventory, Item Detail, Purchase Orders**, and **Customer Info** tables are linked to an external ERP system. These tables are massive and are updated hourly.*

**APPROACH**

1. Due to the sheer size of each table, create smaller queries ("Make table" in Access) that pull in relevant table information (e.g "InventoryQuery" pulls in "ITEM ID" and "ITEM DESCRIPTION" - negating the rest of the 99 columns within the original, ERP table). Repeat this Process for **Item Details**, **Purchase Orders**, and **Customer Details**.
2. Create another query ("*MASTER QUERY*" that joins all of the recently consolidated tables to generate a report.

**ISSUE(S)/QUESTION(S)**

- Correct me if I am wrong, but I believe that "Make Table" queries aren't constantly updated. As a result, the **MASTER QUERY** will not be up-to-date. *How can I modify my **MASTER QUERY** to execute the Make Table queries in real-time?*

EDIT: I've tried creating a MASTER QUERY out of subqueries but, due to the size of the linked tables, the process takes a very long time (>10 min)

Comment: You can't. You should do "Make Tables" to get the aggregate/skinny tables set up, then use "INSERT" queries to add new hourly data to them from your ERP tables. You will have to run those INSERT queries whenever you want to update the data in the tables that were generated from your initial make tables. The way you are wanting to do it would be 100% identical to just having subqueries on your main ERP tables, which you've already determined is too cumbersome.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using Access's report functionality, I've heard good things about it. And I agree with the comment that you need many staging tables rather than a monolithic query with subqueries. However, I would question the decision to create/update your staging tables using Access functionality e.g. Access's stored procedures can only execute a single SQL statement and would be a problem if you needed to drop/create a table before making table/inserting. Look to create staging tables/data on the server side or perhaps another mysql instance between server and Access.